# Deploy gatsby on nginx has wrong redirect address when refresh and brings out port number?

Tags: nginx, gatsby

I hava a website, and deploy the site on nginx in docker container. The proplem is when I refresh the site the chrome address bar brings out the port number and redirect wrong.

I am a front-end progromer and don't hava any server permission. so i can try nothing on back end. On the server side already tried nginx config file but nothing help.

This is the website address:

```
www.haetek.com/case
```

If you refresh brings out port number 8181.

```
www.haetek.com:8181/case
```

I expect normal address redirect.

Comment: Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This qustion is solved just add a slash at the end of the address,

this address

```
www.haetek.com/case
```

to this address

```
www.haetek.com/case/
```

I don't know the detail why it solved the problem. but it worked.